# Centre and right aligned navigation on Bulma. Mobile devices issue

Tags: html, css, bulma

I am using the latest version of Bulma. I am trying to build a static HTML/CSS site. The navigation is rather unconventional. It has centred elements, but also right aligned elements.

On desktops, I'm happy with the look, but on mobile, the whole menu disappears.

[image: issue visual]

I have created a [Codepen](https://codepen.io/Ciwan/pen/mvXvrX).

Here is the code:

**HTML**

```
<section class="hero is-large">
  <div class="hero-head">
    <nav class="navbar" role="navigation" aria-label="main navigation">
      <div class="navbar-brand">
        <a
          role="button"
          class="navbar-burger"
          aria-label="menu"
          aria-expanded="false"
          data-target="nav-menu"
        >
          <span aria-hidden="true"></span>
          <span aria-hidden="true"></span>
          <span aria-hidden="true"></span>
        </a>
      </div>
      <div class="navbar-menu" id="nav-menu">
        <div id="navbarBasicExample" class="navbar-menu">
          <div class="navbar-start navbar-start--centered">
            <a href="">Products</a> <a href="">Our Story</a>
            <a href="http://127.0.0.1:5500/home.html" class="logo">
              <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/b/be/Lineage_OS_Logo.png" width="170" />
            </a>
            <a href="">Blog</a> <a href="">Contact Us</a>
          </div>

          <div class="navbar-end">
            <a class="cart">
              <i class="fas fa-cart-plus"></i> <span>0</span>
            </a>
            <a class="login"> <i class="fas fa-user"></i> Log in </a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>
  </div>
  <div class="hero-body is-hidden-mobile">
    <div class="container"></div>
  </div>
</section>
```

**CSS**

```
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
}

.navbar-start--centered {
  flex-grow: 1;
  justify-content: center;
}

.navbar .navbar-start a {
  padding: 30px 50px;
  color: #194522;
  font-weight: bold;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.navbar .navbar-start a.logo img {
  fill: #194522;
}

.navbar .navbar-start a.logo:hover img,
.navbar .navbar-start a.logo:hover img:hover {
  fill: #abcf39;
}

.navbar .navbar-end a {
  padding: 30px 20px;
  color: #194522;
  font-weight: bold;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.navbar .navbar-start a:hover,
.navbar .navbar-end a:hover {
  color: #abcf39;
}

.navbar .navbar-end a i {
  padding-right: 6px;
}

#logo {
  width: 200px;
  height: 100%;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}

.hero {
  background-color: #f3e2f3;
}
```

What I would like to see on mobile is for that drop down menu to have Products, Our Story, Blog and Contact Us links. I am not sure what I am doing wrong, but I suspect it is because of the unusual menu I have.

Comment: If found that adding `#navbarBasicExample {
  display: flex;
}` solves the problem, and why it works is as, on narrower screen that element gets set to `display: none`. Whether that is a preferred way can't really say as I am not a BULMA user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a class `.navbar-menu` too much. Elements with this class are hidden on mobile. With Javascript the class `is-active` will be added, to make it visible again on mobile – as soon as the the hamburger was clicked this style kicks in:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 1087px)
.navbar-menu.is-active {
    display: block;
}
```

You have a second, nested `.navbar-menu`:

```
<div class="navbar-menu" id="nav-menu">
        <div id="navbarBasicExample" class="navbar-menu"> <!-- still hides menu, even when hamburger was clicked -->
```

You can only use this class once. The nested one never gets the class `is-active` added, so the menu remains hidden.

Comment: Look what happens, when the nested class is removed, the menu works again:
https://codepen.io/Sixl/pen/BMYbzB
(Menu needs additonal styling and overhaul, though)

Comment: Thank you, I totally missed that I had two nested `.navbar-menu` classes.